# Is it possible for a locked phone to vibrate several times with one push notification?

Tags: ios, swift

As per title.

I'd like to send a push notification to a remote user. When the user receives it, the phone vibrates in a custom pattern while locked.

Is this possible? How would it be done?

Comment: I don't think its up to your app. The user has control over custom vibration patterns for each app, but the app doesn't I believe.